# Neo4j Cypher : No of Relations for Each Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the cypher to find the no of edges/relationships of each user/node ?
I want to return that count for each user.

Answer (score 2):

The **fastest way**, uses node.getDegree internally.

You can separate the rel-pattern also by direction and relationship-type.

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n, size((n)--()) as degree
```

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
RETURN n, COUNT(r)
```

but there are several specifications of this pattern that you are likely to want to make. If you have other nodes than users you may want to limit the query to users by giving them and querying for a label. You may also want to count only a particular type of relationship or only a particular direction, so you add those parts of the pattern as well.

If your users are people and you want to query for how many times each user has called other users on the phone the query might look like

```
MATCH (n:Users)-[r:CALLED]->(:User)
RETURN n.name as user , COUNT(r) as phone_calls_made
```

If the `[:CALLED]` relationship only ever obtains between users you can drop the second `:User` label in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Match the `User` and all relationships and return the `count`:

```
MATCH (n:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
RETURN n, count(DISTINCT r)
```